# Iteration between dates in Elixir

Tags: date, iteration, elixir

I am currently working with dates and I want to iterate between 2 dates by increment of a day. my values are

```
timezone =
  case extractor.timezone do
    nil -> "Etc/UTC"
    _ -> extractor.timezone
  end

start_date =
  extractor.from_date
  |> Ecto.DateTime.to_erl
  |> Calendar.DateTime.from_erl!(timezone)

end_date =
  extractor.to_date
  |> Ecto.DateTime.to_erl
  |> Calendar.DateTime.from_erl!(timezone)

total_days = find_difference(end_date, start_date)
IO.inspect iterate(schedule["Friday"], start_date, timezone)
```

my purpose of doing this is, I will iterate between start and end dates. While increasing a day in start date, with calendar am going to fetch the week day of date `Calendar.Date.day_of_week_name` and going to pass it to schedule.

Now am trying to create a loop which may go from start date to end date `Enum` is not helpful to me right now.. any other suggestion that how can i create a loop? for dates

UPDATE: 
I am trying to loop in this way

```
for _ <- 1..total_days do
  day_of_week = start_date |> Calendar.Date.day_of_week_name
  IEx.pry
  IO.inspect iterate(schedule[day_of_week], start_date, timezone)
  start_date = start_date |> Calendar.DateTime.to_erl |> Calendar.DateTime.from_erl!(timezone, {123456, 6}) |> Calendar.DateTime.add!(86400)
end
```

But when loop starts again it dont take the values new start_date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, it does not. Elixir, as any other functional language, has *no mutable variables*. The scope of local variable `start_date`, assigned in the last line, *is the `do`—`end` block*. Basically, what you are doing is producing a new local variable that is immediately GC’ed.

To collect a value, one needs a loop with an accumulator, e. g.:

```
1..total_days |> Enum.reduce(start_date, fn i, acc ->
  day_of_week = acc |> Calendar.Date.day_of_week_name
  IEx.pry
  IO.inspect iterate(schedule[day_of_week], start_date, timezone)
  acc |> .......
end)
```

Now the accumulator `acc`, that receives a value from the block (the last line result,) will store and pass through your `start_date`.

---

*Sidenote*: that might look confusing for those came from languages with mutable objects, but

```
a = a + 1
```

in Elixir *does not change the value of `a`*. It _creates a new local variable `a`, assigning the value of *former variable `a`* to it. There is no connection between LHO `a` and RHO `a` in this line.

Comment: now at the end i need to do as 
`acc |> Calendar.DateTime.to_erl |> Calendar.DateTime.from_erl!(timezone, {123456, 6}) |> Calendar.DateTime.add!(86400)` ?

Comment: In the very last line, you are to produce a value to be passed through as an `acc` value.

Comment: Actually i piped start_date at the end again and it gave me error that why asked!